How to write this symbol ( plus minus in the same vertical line)
I am new to LATEX and I am writing a presentation in it. I am using overleaf subscription and I have searched the symbol there and also on detexify kirelabs but I couldn't find the code of this symbol.
Can you please tell me the code of following symbol:

I shall be grateful.

Sometimes with detexify you need to try drawing the lines in a different order, or click the "Show more" a few times.

It's simply \pm. There's also \mp for minus-plus sign.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$A \pm B$

$C \mp D$

\end{document}


By the way, detexify can give it to you :


Detexify was giving me other symbols.

@Avenger Sometimes you have to try several times.
